# Can you edit WordPress custom post types directly from the archive list page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to  edit WordPress custom post types directly from the archive list page. For example, you would use the "list" view to edit the posts and pages in that custom post type, including all o the custom fields. [image]

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no way. But you can add this feature using custom coding. First you register custom columns using hooks manage_POST-Type-SLUG_posts_columns  and then you do the editing operation using JavaScript Or PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Using a plugin

If you're using ACF, the easiest way to do this would be with [ACF Quick Edit Fields plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-quickedit-fields/).

### Option 2: Using code

If you don't want to use a plugin, you need to:

1. Add columns to the list page
2. Get the fields and display it in these columns

You can add the following code to your theme's `functions.php`:

1. Add columns for the data you want displayed in the list

```php
// Replace 'cpt_name' with your custom post type name
function add_custom_columns ( $columns ) {
  $columns['custom_field_1'] = __( 'Custom Field 1 Column Name' );
  $columns['custom_field_2'] = __( 'Custom Field 2 Column Name' );
  return $columns;
}
add_filter ( 'manage_cpt_name_posts_columns', 'add_custom_columns' );
```

2. Get the fields and display it in the columns

```php
function display_cf_columns ( $column, $post_id ) {
   switch ( $column ) {
     case 'custom_field_1':       
       echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'post_meta_1', true );
       break;
     case 'custom_field_2':
       echo get_post_meta ( $post_id, 'post_meta_1', true );
       break;
   }
 }
 add_action ( 'manage_cpt_name_posts_custom_column', 'display_cf_columns', 10, 2 );
```